# Fluent NHibernate 3.1 error on all queries

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Since upgrading to Fluent NHibernate 3.1, I keep getting errors on all my queries.

For example I have some simple code, like this:

```
public bool isUsernameFree(string username)
{
    return _session.Query<User>()
        .Where(u => u.username == username).Count() == 0;
}
```

But it always fails with the error:

> The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Linq.NhRelinqQueryParser' threw
>   an exception. Sequence contains more than one matching element

Does anyone know what's going on? It worked fine in the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue when running under mstest

- http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/c7729f6d56dc022f
- http://groups.google.com/group/re-motion-users/browse_thread/thread/565a652b03682092

Comment: I've seen this link but I'm not using mstest.